# iOS Xamarin Attaching a picture to the Email Body - Null Exception

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, email-attachments

I am using my first Xamarin iOS app to take a picture, extract meta data of the picture, attach the picture to an email body and send email.

// (1.) Take a photo with the Camera //

```
  partial void BtnCamera_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)

            {
                UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
                imagePicker.PrefersStatusBarHidden();
                imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

                // handle saving picture and extracting meta-data from picture //
                imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;

                // present //
                PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, () => { });

            }
```

// (2.) Saves the image to the phone and then extracts metadata //

```
protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)

    {
        //NSUrl url = null;  
        try
        {
            #region Save Image and Get Meta-data 

            // Save Image before processing for meta-data //
            SaveImagetoPhone(e);
            // Get meta-data from saved image //
            GetImageMetaData(e);
```

// (3.) Save picture to the phone and extract photo url //

```
private static void SaveImagetoPhone(UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        NSUrl url = null;

void ImageData(PHAsset asset)
{
    if (asset == null)
        throw new Exception("PHAsset is null");
     PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
                {

                    url = info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey")) as NSUrl;
                    PhotoDataClass._file = url.Path;          

});  }

PHAsset phAsset;
if (e.ReferenceUrl == null)
{
    e.OriginalImage?.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
    {
        if (error == null)
        {
            var options = new PHFetchOptions
            {
                FetchLimit = 1,
                SortDescriptors = new[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", true) }
            };
            phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).LastOrDefault() as PHAsset;
            ImageData(phAsset);
        }
    });
}
else
{
    phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(new[] { e.ReferenceUrl }, null).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;
    ImageData(phAsset);
}
```

}

At this point I have successfully extracted the URL for the file:-
***"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0036.JPG"***

However when I run my email function, even though the url is populated, I get a null exception without any explanation that I know of.

// (4.) Email functionality //
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/email/send_an_email/

```
partial void BtnMessageDone_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController mailController;
        if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
        {
            StringBuilder htmlBodyMail = FormatEmailBody();
            mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
            // do mail operations here
            mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { "xxx.yy@email.com" });
            mailController.SetSubject("mail test");
            mailController.SetMessageBody(htmlBodyMail.ToString(), false);
            UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile(PhotoDataClass._file);
            mailController.AddAttachmentData(img.AsJPEG(), "image/JPG", "Image.JPG");
            mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Result.ToString());
                args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };
            this.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
        }
    }
```

The null exception occurs on the line inside the email functionality:- 
 mailController.AddAttachmentData(img.AsJPEG(), "image/JPG", "Image.JPG");

Comment: Either the NS URL  I m extracting is not what is expected by the email functionality or the way I am extract that data for the image in line:- phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).LastOrDefault() as PHAsset;
That LastOrDefault() is not what I think it is

Comment: When I manually attach the picture to an email and send the email.. I get a picture with photo ID - IMG_0036.JPG. So that tells me that the picture does exist and has a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the image will be null when you use `UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile(PhotoDataClass._file);`. So this null exception will be thrown.

We should use `PHAsset` to retrieve image from system photo library instead of using the url directly. You can store the `LocalIdentifier` to the class `PhotoDataClass`, then retrieve the PHAsset through this identifier when you want to use it later.

Modify the `ImageData` method:

```
void ImageData(PHAsset asset)
{
    if (asset == null)
        throw new Exception("PHAsset is null");

    PhotoDataClass.AssetIdentifier = asset.LocalIdentifier;
}
```

Then `BtnMessageDone_TouchUpInside` method can be:

```
MFMailComposeViewController mailController;
if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
{
    var results = PHAsset.FetchAssetsUsingLocalIdentifiers(new string[] { PhotoDataClass.AssetIdentifier }, null);
    foreach (PHAsset asset in results)
    {
        if (asset.LocalIdentifier == PhotoDataClass.AssetIdentifier)
        {
            PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
            {

                StringBuilder htmlBodyMail = FormatEmailBody();
                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
                // do mail operations here
                ...
                UIImage img = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                mailController.AddAttachmentData(img.AsJPEG(), "image/JPG", "Image.JPG");
                ...

            });
        }
    }
}
```

> Moreover That LastOrDefault() is not what I think it is

This is because your `NSSortDescriptor`, use `SortDescriptors = new[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false) }` or `phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;` to get your photo you just capture from your camera.